# SQL Query - Get the latest rates

Tags: sql, sql-server

My Table:

```
Date              Code        Rate
----              ----        ----
2015-01-01          1         100
2015-01-01          2         200
2015-01-01          3         300
2015-06-01          1         150
```

How can i get the latest rates(By Date), like:

```
Date              Code        Rate
----              ----        ----
2015-01-01          2         200
2015-01-01          3         300
2015-06-01          1         150
```

SQL Query?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Take a look at `ROW_NUMBER`

Comment: use `group by Code` with `select max(Rate) as Rate`

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Code ORDER BY Date DESC) rn
    FROM yourtable
)
SELECT 
        Date, 
        Code, 
        Rate
FROM cte 
WHERE rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with sub-query
Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM your_table ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 5
) sub
ORDER BY date ASC
```

This code gets the last 5 rows from your table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select  Date,
        Code,
        Rate
from    (
            select  ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by    code order by   date desc)as Id,date,code,rate
            from    yourTable
        ) x
where   Id = 1
order by    date
```